# Android Apps: Exit vs Minimize

Tags: android, back-button

Is there an Android standard or coding convention / best practice that says whether or not an app should Exit (not running in background) or minimize (running in background) when the user "backs-out" of an app?

For example, you are on the home page of an app. What is the best-practice for handling the back press?
The obvious answer is to let android handle it's own back button press, which in turn exits the app. But is it okay to override and minimize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help

"App follows Android Design guidelines and uses common UI patterns and icons:
App does not redefine the expected function of a system icon (such as the Back button)".

[Android Core Standard Policies](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/core.html)

Comment: Glad I could help. I found that resource a few weeks ago and it is very informative

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the kind of application you are making in my opinion.
If for example you have an application that needs to save something to a database or whatever when the user clicks the back button, I would agree you just minimize the app. But even then, after the app has done saving, it should exit.

But if possible I would suggest you exit the application, this will also let the phone free up memory/CPU which can be used by other applications etc. It will also save battery.

And of course, this is the expected behaviour for an Android user: If you go back, you close the application. You don't want to confuse your users ;-)

Comment: I agree the app shouldn't change the default behavior (exiting) and your other points are great. Thank you

Comment: Careful -- if the system thinks the app isn't running it can kill it at any time.  If it's in the middle of updating a database or other persistent storage you might lose data.  Use `Settings > Developer Options > Don't keep activities` for testing.